# Nativescript preview button shows QR code only

Tags: nativescript

how can i get this preview window. Earlier I got it very first time only.  now when i click "Preview" button it shows QR code for mobile[preview window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2bY4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure: What happens when you click on `QR code` button shown in the print screen?

Answer (score 0):

Install the companion apps NativeScript Playground and NativeScript Preview on a device with iOS or Android and scan that QR code (using NativeScript Playground)

You'll see on your device a preview of the app from the playground.

Check this page [Step 3: Install the NativeScript Playground app](https://docs.nativescript.org/start/quick-setup#step-3-install-the-nativescript-playground-app) with direct links to the apps and more details about this workflow.